# Get value from assigned variable that has been scoped from global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I've come into a problem - I have some jQuery code that gets `window` height everytime the user resizes it. However, I need to pass that value to another part of the code that's not within the function; and unsurprisingly, the code doesn't recognize the usage of the `winHeight` outside the function. It looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Calls function when window is resized
    $(window).resize(getWinHeight);

    var winHeight;
    function getWinHeight() {
        winHeight = window.innerHeight; // I want to get the value of winHeight

    // When the button is clicked
    var button = document.getElementById("button_container");
    $(button).click(function() {
        $("#middle").css("display", "block");
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: winHeight}, 500); // winHeight isn't recognized!!
   });
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph8y8zaq/1/) that might help you get a better picture of the problem.

Comment: So,  what exactly is the issue? How does your code fail?

Comment: As it says in the comment of the code, `winHeight` isn't recognized.

Comment: Seems to work as intented?

Comment: In the jsFiddle, the window is suppose to scroll down - but it's not.

Comment: Well, that fiddle does scroll down, and the variable is recognized... https://image.prntscr.com/image/Tt3QOyP2T3eZxouDD54nrQ.png hence the confusion ....

Comment: That's weird... I don't know why it's not working for me :( - any alternatives to do the same thing I'm trying to do?

Comment: You didn't initialised `winHeight`, so first time it will say undefined, after you resize it will work.

You can initialize by `var winHeight=window.innerHeight;` and it will work fine.

Comment: I checked your jsFiddle and it seems like your variable is indeed getting updated.

Take a look at this modified jsFiddle, where I print the variable to the console when the button is clicked:

https://jsfiddle.net/ph8y8zaq/2/

You might also want to initialize winHeight to window.innerHeight, depending on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you [JagsSparrow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2285490/jagssparrow), the initialization of the variable worked. But my question is, how does the value of `winHeight` update when the window is resized?